# jQuery - Multiple click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem. I just started learning jQuery, my first experience with javascript at all. And I want to make an element animate on click, and I did make that work:

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Testing</h1>
```

I'm using Animate.css to make some animations happen on click. Here's my jQuery:

```
$('h1').click(function (e) { 

            $('h1').addClass('animated bounce');

        });
```

What I want to achieve is that when I click 2nd time, the animation happens again, in fact, I want to remove the **animated bounce** class and add it again, that way the animation will happen again.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <h1>Testing</h1>
  
  
  <script>

  
  $('h1').click(function (e) { 
          $('h1').addClass('animated bounce');
           
        });
  </script>

</body>
```

And please tell me if I'm doing the code the way it should be, I mean if the syntax is fine, I've seen codes with **$(this)** and I'm not sure what that is, also I've seen something like **.on('click')**

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the CSS class once the animation is over.

```js
$('h1').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('animated bounce').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
    $(this).removeClass();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<h1>Testing</h1>
```

For the rest, your syntax is fine.

Some notes:

- `e` is an object based on Event describing the event which has occurred. It is optional. If you don't need data from the event you can skip it.
- `$(this)` is a jQuery object. In the context of the callback, it is the element which invokes the function. In JavaScript, the `this` keyword is a very important and complex topic. You can read about it in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and here in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/5247200).
- [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) is an event handler attacher that ensures the handler is executed just one time.
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is other attacher. Have a look to [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click) to learn when to use `click()` or `on('click')`.

Comment: This is working perfectly, Just as I wanted. Thank You.
What does ".one(....)" part do?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```js
$('h1').on("click", function() {
  $(this).addClass('animated bounce');
  setTimeout(()=> $(this).removeClass('animated bounce'), 1000);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Testing</h1>

</body>
```

You use the `toggleClass` method - it *toggles* whether the element has the class, as the name would suggest.

Comment: This would be the correct answer but i have to double click it after the 2nd try.

Comment: Not my question, just wanting to upvote your answer :)

Comment: @MojoAllmighty Yes, fixed, done! Does it work now? (also don't hesitate for the voting)

Comment: You're probably better off using `setTimeout` after animation finishes

Comment: It's broken now,
Well I'm new to jQuery so You guys help me :)

Comment: Oh, it's working now with setTimeout. I get it. Thank You!